# Retrieve exists consecutive lines value VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I should show if there is a consecutive value of lines, if the line contains consecutive values. when it contains at least 2, to display something, when it does not contain, to display something else.
Like my Textbox:
Textbox1.Text = `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20`

```
 For x As Integer = 1 To 4

    Next
```

if I have

```
2
4

4

10
22
```

can i somehow show if there are consecutive lines?

```
MsgBox("Exist")
```

Else

```
  2

    4

    22

  25

MsgBox("Not Exists")
```

Comment: What is your declaration of `lines`? Is it an array or a file or what? please add the declaration to your code snippet.

Comment: Array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextBoxes have a `Lines property, which makes it easy to retrieve lines

```
'Get the lines from the textbox
Dim lines As String() = Textbox1.Lines

If lines.Length >= 2 Then
    Dim consecutiveLines As Boolean = False
    Dim previousLine As String = lines(0)
    For i = 1 To lines.Length - 1
        Dim currentLine = lines(i)
        If currentLine = previousLine Then
            consecutiveLines = True
            Exit For
        End If
        previousLine = currentLine
    Next

    If consecutiveLines Then
        'Display somthing
    Else
        'Display somthing else
    End If
End If
```

The trick is to start looping at the second line (`lines(1)`) and to compare it with the previous line. We have to update the previous line at the end of each loop.

We also store the outcome in a Boolean variable `consecutiveLines`.

Alternatively, we could access two consecutive lines directly:

```
'Get the lines from the textbox
Dim lines As String() = Textbox1.Lines

If lines.Length >= 2 Then
    Dim consecutiveLines As Boolean = False
    For i = 1 To lines.Length - 1 'Start at second line
        If lines(i) = lines(i - 1) Then
            consecutiveLines = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If consecutiveLines Then
        'Display somthing
    Else
        'Display somthing else
    End If
End If
```

This leads to a somewhat shorter code.

Comment: he calculates for example it works when in line there is the same value, the problem is that if we have numbers that do not repeat, it does not work. example: works with 4 and 4, but will not work with 7 2, the results will be different. I will probably have to look for a condition, here must be the problem: If currentLine = previousLine Then

Comment: I think I managed to do it using the following code: If currentLine.Length> 0 AndAlso previousLine.Length> 0 Then

Comment: Ignoring empty lines was not part of your question. If you want to ignore empty lines, you should not assign empty lines to `previousLine`. I.e.: `Dim currentLine = lines(i)
    If currentLine.Length > 0 Then
        If currentLine = previousLine Then
            consecutiveLines = True
            Exit For
        End If
        previousLine = currentLine
    End If`. Inside the For-loop, everything after `Dim currentLine = lines(i)` is enclosed in `If currentLine.Length > 0 Then ... End If`.

Comment: I changed the code just like that, and it seems to work fine after I tested it. If currentLine.Length> 0 AndAlso previousLine.Length> 0 Then otherwise it remains the same, in fact this code I think should check the length, to see if there is something greater than 0 on the line. it is too complicated the changes you told me. I think it's ok and as I did make, I hope.

Comment: The code was actually: If currentLine = previousLine Then, that is, probably if currentline is identical to previousline, which cannot happen if we have different values. after I made the change, I say and I hope it will be as good as I did.

Comment: in fact it is not just about empty lines, and it simply did not work if we had for example 7 and 2 on 2 consecutive lines. but if I had 7 7 it would work.

Comment: Ohh, I understand! I thought you wanted to detect 2 **equal** consecutive lines; however, you want to detect 2 **non-empty** consecutive lines (no matter its contents).

Comment: not empty, and 2 lines consecutive have something, like 2 7 or 7 2.